# Python(Spyder) : An error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python, spyder

I have installed python xy and spyder. After installing xy, I installed spyder and the following error code occurred. The same problem arises if you reorder the installation.
Please let me know what the problem is!

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1544, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
config=None, autorestart=True)
File"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 73, in __init__
super(Configurable, self).__init__(**kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 997, in __init__
setattr(self, key, value)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 585, in __set__
self.set(obj, value)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 559, in set
new_value = self._validate(obj, value)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 591, in _validate
value = self.validate(obj, value)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 2053, in validate
raise TraitError(msg.format(value, self.name, class_of(obj)))
TraitError: Could not decode 
'C:\\Users\\\xc1\xd8\xb8\xf0\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernelb782c4f5507.json' for unicode trait 'connection_file' of a QtKernelManager instance.
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This most probably happens because you have a Windows user name with special characters (i.e. characters not present in the English alphabet). So you have two options here: 1. Change your user name to something that doesn't have those characters; or 2. Move to use Python 3, which has much better support for those kind of characters.

Comment: WOw!!!!! It is resolved!!! thanks a lot!!